# Paperwhite error on open book, how do I get the error log?

Tags: mobi, kindle-paperwhite

I downloaded a `.mobi` file format [book from Baen](http://www.baenebooks.com/p-1597-free-nonfiction-2012.aspx) it opens fine on Calibre, and on my Kindle keyboard.  When I try to open it on my Kindle Paperwhite I get this message

```
 Error
```

---

```
 An error occurred. 
 If you purchased this item from Amazon, 
 delete the item and download it from the cloud.
```

---

```
OK
```

I have reloaded it to the Paperwhite twice, to validate it is not a one time error, I have not got a new download from Baen yet.

I would like to know if/how I can identify what the error is.  This is a DRM free work, and before reading it on another device or getting a new download from the publisher I would like to try and use Calibre to correct the error.  It would seem that identifying the error would be the first step.

Does the Paperwhite keep an error log, and if so how can I access it?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think they make an app for the PaperWhite since it would appear it is Amazon content dedicated and not based of Android because I recall being able to install error logging apps from Android on my Kindle.

Since this is a DRM free book I would omit the usage of Calibre.  That said I would download [Kindle Previewer](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000765261) and browse the book for any possibly display issues and see if you can duplicate the error.

If you have found no display issues or get any errors when viewing the book through [Kindle Previewer](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000765261) I would install [KindleGen](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000765211) and unpack the `.mobi` file back to `.epub` format.  Then run the `.epub` file through [IDPF validation](http://validator.idpf.org/).  If you want you could edit the `.epub` file in Calibre but I would do it manually, that's just me, and then you can use [KindleGen](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000765211) to convert back to `.mobi` format.

If you find any issues and have paid for the book I would contact the buyer and inform them you have an issue with the `.mobi` file and would like a refund if you cant correct the issue.