# If you purchased this item from Amazon, delete the item and download it from the Cloud

Tags: kindle, ebook-readers, amazon, ebook-management, drm

I'll probably end up asking Amazon for a refund on:

> XQuery: Search Across a Variety of XML Data
>
> Product details
>
> ```
> Paperback: 762 pages
> Publisher: O'Reilly Media; 2 edition (Jan. 7 2016)
> Language: English
> ISBN-10: 9781491915103
> ISBN-13: 978-1491915103
> ASIN: 1491915102
> ```

due to a persistent error:

> Error
>
> An error occurred.  If you purchased this item from Amazon, delete the
>   item and download it from the Cloud.

Short of setting the Kindle to factory defaults I'm at a loss, but can speculate that perhaps the code in the book might be causing some problems.

see also:

[Paperwhite error on open book, how do I get the error log?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/1142/9853)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you downloaded a partial file or it was corrupted somehow. Just delete it from your device and try again. (Alternatively, remove it by going  to [Manage Your Content and Devices](https://www.amazon.com/hz/mycd/myx?ie=UTF8&ref_=nav_youraccount_myk#/home/content/booksAll/dateDsc/).

Don't delete the ebook from all devices, just the one device you are working on.

Failing that, you can also contact Oreilly or even the author and include a receipt. Oreilly is a great publisher, and they would probably be able to send you via email  the file to you if you asked nicely.

Quality control on Oreilly ebooks is  pretty high. I doubt there's a formatting issue. The file is 5mb, not too big. But it might be worthwhile trying to view it on a Kindle app on a tablet or on Kindle for PC Desktop.

Occasionally I have an issue downloading certain ebooks. Often it's a matter of just deleting the first version you downloading and retrying. Sometimes it gets stuck, but I'm generally able to download everything. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm getting this same error, and I've deleted and re-downloaded the book thrice now. I don't think this is a universal fix.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I contacted Amazon to solve it. The problem was a software update. Apparently, my kindle did not update vis wifi, so I updated it via manually via their website.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Updating the firmware to v5.13.3 solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried hard reset in my kindle paperwhite and it solved the problem. 
just hold the power button for 20 seconds and let it restart.

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue as well

Fix that works for me:

1. Delete book
2. Restart kindle
3. Download book
4. Read book

I read somewhere that it could be an issue relating to low battery, but this morning it happened with 54% power.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I called the customer service. They said before I had bought the book and since I also had a kindle unlimited account, the book was just being borrowed. But my subscription ended and I could not borrow it anymore. The issue got fixed once I hard restarted the kindle as per the instructions from the customer service representative.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and:

1. Program Calibre and MOBI to AZW3
2. Download book AZW3
   and is OK